# PUT upload a file's byte range with streams and progress

Tags: http, go, upload, progress

I just got started with Go and need some help. I would like to upload a certain range of bytes from a file.

I already accomplished this by reading the bytes into a buffer. But this increases memory usage.
Instead of reading bytes into memory, I want to stream them while uploading and have an upload progress. I did something like this in Node.js but struggle to get the puzzle pieces together for Go.
The code that I have now looks like this:

```
func uploadChunk(id, mimeType, uploadURL, filePath string, offset, size uint) {
    // open file
    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    panicCheck(err, ErrorFileRead) // custom error handler
    defer file.Close()

    // move to the proper byte
    file.Seek(int64(offset), 0)

    // read byte chunk into buffer
    buffer := make([]byte, size)
    file.Read(buffer)
    fileReader := bytes.NewReader(buffer)

    request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPut, uploadURL, fileReader)

    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 10,
    }

    response, err := client.Do(request)
    panicCheck(err, ErrorFileRead)

    defer response.Body.Close()

    b, err := httputil.DumpResponse(response, true)
    panicCheck(err, ErrorFileRead)
    fmt.Println("response\n", string(b))
}
```

Could you guys help me to figure out how to stream and get progress for an upload?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not understanding the example, because you have a `file`, but you don't do anything with it. Don't you just use that file as the body for the `NewRequest`?

Comment: thanks @JimB, I just edited the example code. I missed adding `file.Read(buffer)`

Comment: Yes, but why not just pass `file` directly to `http.NewRequest`?

Comment: @JimB I only want to upload a range of bytes from a file. Not the whole file. That's why I am doing the `file.Seek(offset, 0)`. The function's arguments take an offset and a size. Size determines how many bytes should be read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`io.LimitedReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#LimitReader) to wrap the file and only read the amount of data you want. The implementation returned by [`io.LimitReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#LimitReader) is an `*io.LimitedReader`.

```
file.Seek(int64(offset), 0)
fileReader := io.LimitReader(file, size)

request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPut, uploadURL, fileReader)
```

And for S3 you will want to ensure that you don't use chunked encoding by explicitly setting the ContentLength:

```
request.ContentLength = size
```

As for upload progress, see: [Go: Tracking POST request progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050380/go-tracking-post-request-progress)

Comment: Looks like what I need but in conjunction with the PUT upload, it gives me a `501 Not Implemented` server error. `<Message>A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented</Message><Header>Transfer-Encoding</Header>`. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: @ThomasSzabo: does this happen to be from S3?

Comment: exactly. I'm trying to upload to S3 with a presigned URL

Comment: @ThomasSzabo: S3 is odd (and non-compliant) in that it doesn't accept chunked encoding. Try setting `request.ContentLength = size`.

Comment: Oh wow! That fixed the 501 error. I tried it with `request.Header.Set("Content-Length", fmt.Sprintf("%d", size))` before but didn't worked.

Comment: what do you think of the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050380/go-tracking-post-request-progress

Would that solve the progress reporting?

Comment: @ThomasSzabo: I missed that you wanted upload progress too, you basically have 2 completely separate questions here. Yes that answer shows the basis of what you need.